# How do I insert records from one table to another when some records don't fit a FK constraint?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a source table that has 10,000 records that I want to insert into a destination table. The insert would also include an ID field. There is a third table with a foreign key relationship on the id field. How do I insert the records that have the correct ids for the FK and skip the ones that don't have the correct ids for the FK?

```
Set IDENTITY_INSERT Destination ON
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Destination]
           (
           Id,
           [Street1]
           ,[Street2]
           ,[City]
           ,[State]
           ,[PostalCode]
           ,[ContactId]
           ,[Institution_ID]
           ,[LegacyIDNumber]
           )
 SELECT DISTINCT
 [Account Number],
    [Address],
    [Address 2],
    [City],
    Left([State],2),
    [Postal Code],
    [Account Number],
    [Account Number],
    [Account Number]
FROM  [dbo].[Source]
GO

Set IDENTITY_INSERT Destination OFF
GO
```

The error I get is

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Destination_dbo.Contacts_ContactId". The conflict occurred in database "xxxx", table "dbo.Contacts", column 'Id'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add an INNER JOIN to the Contacts table to ensure that the `[Account Number]` from the source matches the `Id` in the Contacts table. Anything that doesn't match would get filtered out which should keep you from getting the error about the FK constraint.

```
SELECT [Account Number],
    [Address],
    [Address 2],
    [City],
    Left([State],2),
    [Postal Code],
    [Account Number],
    [Account Number],
    [Account Number]
FROM  [dbo].[Source]
INNER JOIN dbo.Contacts ON Contacts.id=Source.[Account Number]
```

There is probably a query hint or some other database trick that would allow you to pull this off more properly. But AFAIK the above should work.

Comment: Worked great for my purposes.